# How to re-render view on creating new entry to model in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am backbone.js newbee.
I have a Bookmark Model, in my Rails application. I am trying to create a text field in which when I enter text and click submit button it should create entry and display it in the views so that I don't need to refresh the page to see the new entry.

I have written following Backbone.js code:

```
var BookmarksModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/bookmarks",
})

 var enterBookmarkView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#divForBookmarks"),
        events: {
            "click #submit" : "submitBookmark"
        },
        initialize: function(){

        this.model.bind('change',this.render)
        this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            alert("Render Called!");
            var temp = _.template( $("#enterBookmark").html(), {} );
            $(this.el).html(temp);
            return this;
        },
        submitBookmark : function(){
            var BM={
                url: $("#bookmark").val(),
                tag_list: $("#tags").val()
            }
            this.model.save(BM);
            this.render();
        }
    });

var mymodel=new BookmarksModel();
var enter_bookmark_view = new enterBookmarkView({ model: mymodel });
```

However, this does create new entry, but is not displayed instantaneously, I need to refresh the page to see the new  entry. I am calling render function on the change event of the model so this should work, right? also, I have called it in the function submitBookmark so that it atleast re-render when the function is called but that din't work either. Also, is this the standard way to create new entry into our Model through views?

Comment: Do you have errors? They should be.

Comment: Atleast none reported to my console.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to try is using `console.log()` or stepping through with the debugger to make sure that `this` has the value that you expect each time you reference it.

If you find that `this` has an unexpected value somewhere along the line, check out Underscore.js's `bind()`: http://underscorejs.org/#bind.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a semicolon missing after your bind event. 
Also, in the extend of your backbone-model the object has a comma too many. This will crash in internet explorer.

Here's an update to your code:

```
 var BookmarksModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot: "/bookmarks"
 })

 var enterBookmarkView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#divForBookmarks"),
        events: {
            "click #submit" : "submitBookmark"
        },
        initialize: function(){

    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        alert("Render Called!");
        var temp = _.template( $("#enterBookmark").html(), {} );
        $(this.el).html(temp);
        return this;
    },
    submitBookmark : function(){
        var BM={
            url: $("#bookmark").val(),
            tag_list: $("#tags").val()
        }
        this.model.save(BM);
    }
});

var mymodel=new BookmarksModel();
var enter_bookmark_view = new enterBookmarkView({ model: mymodel });
```

Comment: This has the same problem, I have to refresh the page to get the new added entry displayed.